# Unable to get aws security-group output data using Terraform 0.12

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group

I am trying to query the values of the created vpc and security group, I was able to get the vpc id however I'm failing to get the security group  id.

**MY CODE**

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:pogimo123"
    values = ["TRUE"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "subnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["*_pogimo123"]
  }
}

data "aws_security_groups" "security-groups" {

  filter {
    name   = "group-name"
    values = ["pogimo123"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = ["${data.aws_vpc.vpc.id}"]
  }
}

output "vpc-id" {
 value ="${data.aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}

output "security-groups" {
 value ="${data.aws_security_groups.security-groups.id}"
}
```

**RESULT**

```
POGIMO123_PC:test-terraform pogimo123$ terraform apply
data.aws_vpc.vpc: Refreshing state...
data.aws_security_groups.security-groups: Refreshing state...
data.aws_subnet_ids.subnets: Refreshing state...

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

security-groups = terraform-20200731142029499400000002
vpc-id = vpc-6d012345
```

Notice on the output logs, it shows the proper value of the vpc while the security-groups shows:

```
security-groups = terraform-20200731142029499400000002
```

This result still keeps on showing even if I already placed the absolute value of vpc-id and name of the security group form the terraform code

Comment: Is that your full code? The `aws_security_groups` data source doesn't have an `id` attribute so should error if you try to access it. As with all plural data sources it returns an `ids` attribute instead which is a list of all the IDs of security groups that you can then index or handle appropriately.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - you are correct, I made it worked now. I just made it singular by changing "aws_security_groups" to "aws_security_group"

Answer (score 0):

```
**Terraform v0.14.7**

data "aws_security_groups" "all_worker_mgmt" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
  }
}

output "security_groups" {
  description = "ID of aws_security_groups"
  value       = data.aws_security_groups.all_worker_mgmt.ids
}
```